# How to reset a count (X) variable in SQL

Tags: sql, count

Hello Stackoverflow gurus. I have the following SQL code (thanks stackoverflow people!) and it works fine, but I want to reset count value after each iteration. How to do that within the SQL? Thanks again

```
SELECT COALESCE (SUM (MONETARY_AMOUNT), 0) AS total
  FROM (SELECT ACCOUNT,
               LINE_DESCR,
               MONETARY_AMOUNT,
               COUNT (CASE account WHEN '513901' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER ()
                  AS can_be_negative
          FROM PS_JRNL_LN
         WHERE     SETTLEMENT_DT = '30-DEC-2021'
               AND EMPLID = '000003080'
               AND JOURNAL_ID LIKE 'HR%'
               AND (ACCOUNT = '270400' OR ACCOUNT LIKE '51%'))
WHERE (ACCOUNT LIKE '51%' OR LINE_DESCR = 'DEF') OR can_be_negative > 0;
```

Comment: Your `COUNT (CASE account WHEN '513901' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` is wonky.. `COUNT()` counts the presence of any value as 1, and absence of any value (presence of null) as 0, so `SELECT COUNT(0)` is 1, not 0. Use `SUM` or omit the `ELSE` or say `ELSE NULL` if the intention is to count the number of times 513901 occurs in the account column in the entire table

Comment: *I want to reset count value after each iteration* - SQL doesn't do "iterations", it does "sets". If you want to count the number of tiems N occurs in a set, you group by N. If you need to use that count elsewhere you join it to where you need it based on N equality in the elsewhere and the group (window functions conceptually perform a per-row auto join on the partitioned values)

Comment: thanks Caius for the quick response. I'm only using Count as a switch to detect if account 513901 exists for a given Emplid/Settlement Date combo. When run one time, this works. When run within a process, it doesn't work because count keeps counting.. I wanted to reset count after each "set" in the SQL is run as part of a larger process. I wanted to do the reset from the actual SQL. Is that possible? thanks again

Comment: It doesn't really make sense; you need to give more info about your overall goals. Your COUNT as given does not detect the presence or absence of a particular number; you might as well replace it with COUNT(*)

Comment: Which elements of the given SQL are dynamic/parameterized when the process is running?

Comment: good question. The Settlement date and Emplid are dynamic. I replaced  "              COUNT (CASE account WHEN '513901' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER ()
                  AS can_be_negative" with "COUNT (CASE account WHEN '513901' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) OVER (PARTITION BY JRNL_LN_REF, SETTLEMENT_DT)
                  AS CAN_BE_NEGATIVE" and this does give a new count for each group of Settlement date/emplid combo, but not always

Comment: sorry about that, JRNL_LN_REF is the same as EMPLID

Comment: OK, it's working now. I added the above statement, and checked for CAN_BE_NEGATIVE > 0. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Under what circumstances would you change the `'513901'` and what would you change it to?